# Не выполняется update-запрос Laravel

Tags: update, laravel5

На страничку выгружаются данные из базы.У каждой строки есть своя кнопка, которая отвечает за отображение данных на главной странице (1 - отобразить, 0 - скрыть).

```
 @if($product->visible == 1)
        <form action="{{ route('visibleFalse', $product->id) }}" method="post">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            {{ method_field('patch') }}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" title="Скрыть"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        </form>
    @elseif($product->visible == 0)
        <form action="{{ route('visibleTrue', $product->id) }}" method="post">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            {{ method_field('patch') }}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" title="Показать"><i class="fa fa-eye-slash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        </form>
    @endif
```

Соответственно, работает только кнопка с **title="Скрыть"**. Почему не работает вторая -  не могу понять..Вот код контроллера и роутов. 
**Контроллер:**

```
public function visibleTrue(Product $product)
{
    $product->update(request(['visible', 1]));
    return redirect('/adminpanel/products');
}

public function visibleFalse(Product $product)
{
    $product->update(request(['visible', 0]));
    return redirect('/adminpanel/products');
}
```

**Роуты:**

```
Route::patch('/adminpanel/products/false/{product}', 'Admin\ProductController@visibleFalse')->name('visibleFalse');
Route::patch('/adminpanel/products/true/{product}', 'Admin\ProductController@visibleTrue')->name('visibleTrue');
```

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в данной проблеме. Всем заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Ответ найден через познание)

```
public function visibleTrue(Product $product)
{
    $product->update(['visible' => 1]);
    return redirect('/adminpanel/products');
}

public function visibleFalse(Product $product)
{
    $product->update(['visible' => 0]);
    return redirect('/adminpanel/products');
}
```

Моя ошибка была в том, что я пытался установить разные значения по дефолту в request(), а надо было в массив параметров для update().